# why does the google image link throw me to google search

Tags: html, forms, hyperlink

I am writing a short HTML code, which let us making a research in google image. But the problem is that it is always getting us to Google search, and I don't understand why.
Here si my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="right" href="ggsearch.html">Google search</p></a>
        <div></div>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <form action="https://images.google.com/search">
            <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="The image you are looking for">
            <input type="submit" value="Google Image">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The CSS code is in another file, it is just placing the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your form action to `http://images.google.com/images`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Search</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="right" href="ggsearch.html">Google search</a>
        <div></div>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <form action="http://images.google.com/images">
            <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="The image you are looking for">
            <input type="submit" value="Google Image">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helped :)